# Define an order for ManyToManyField with Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to define the order of objects related through a ManyToManyField?

Example:

- ArticleContainer1 contains in this order :
     article1, article2, article3, article6
- ArticleContainer2 contains in this order :
   article3, article2, article1, article4
- ArticleContainer3 contains in this order :
   article5

Here are my classes :

```
class Article(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ArticleContainer(models.Model):
   contents = models.ManyToManyField(Article, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So this is an example I have, a site that organizes people into departments with per department ordering. Its the same concept as your problem but with different models. This example uses many-to-many through table.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name    = _(u'Slug'),
        help_text           = _(u'Uri identifier for this department.'),
        max_length=255
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name    = _(u'Department Name'),
        help_text           = _(u'The department\'s name.'),
        max_length      = 255
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name    = _(u'Description'),
        help_text           = _(u'Department\'s description')
    )
    people = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through             = 'DepartmentPeople',
        related_name    = 'people',
        verbose_name    = _(u'People'),
        help_text           = _(u'People in this Department')
    )
    order_by = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name    = _(u'Ordering Weight'), 
        help_text           = _(u'This item\'s weight within a list.'),
        max_length      = 255
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Department")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Departments")
        ordering = ['order_by',]

    def people_list(self):
        return [dp.person for dp in DepartmentPeople.objects.filter(department=self).order_by('order')]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the through model:

```
class DepartmentPeople(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        verbose_name    = _(u'Person'),
        help_text           = _(u'Person is a member of this deparment.'),
    )
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        verbose_name    = _(u'Department'),
        help_text           = _(u'Pseron is a member of this department.'),
    )       
    order = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name    = _(u'Order'),
        help_text           = _(u'What order to display this person within the department.'),
        max_length      = 255
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Department Person")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Department People")
        ordering = ['order',]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.person.first_name + " " + self.person.last_name + " is a member of " + self.department.name + (" in position %d" % self.order)
```

And the admin:

```
class DepartmentPeopleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DepartmentPeople
    extra = 1

class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (DepartmentPeopleInline,)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
admin.site.register(Department, DepartmentAdmin)
```

## REQUEST IN COMMENT:

Note: the following is my PersonAdmin, but its needlessly complicated for this example. you could get by with a simple

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) :
    pass
```

BUT this is what i'm using in my app:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    abstract = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Person

class PersonAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin):
    form = PersonForm
    # The Form Fieldsets
    fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                'fields'    : [('first_name', 'last_name', 'post_nominal', ), 'slug', 'title', 'headshot', 'large_photo', ('email', 'phone', ), 'abstract']
            },
        )
    ]

    # Prepopulated fields
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'post_nominal', )}

    # Fields that are readonly
    #readonly_fields = ('slug', )

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'headshot':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = AdminImageWidget
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(PersonAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

Comment: do I put the Admin code next to the register? sorry I'm noob in Django

Comment: I will test it tonight, it seems Good

Comment: You need to put your admin class definitions before you register them. I edited my answer to show how.

Comment: Can you add PersonAdmin Definition to your answer please?

Comment: Did you end up testing out this solution? Did it work for your needs?

Comment: Solid example, very thorough.

Comment: Any way to do the ordering in serializers with drf for ManyToMany Fields with through?

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad yes there is, but its not something I have code laying around for. did you figure it out or do you need something whipped up?

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello do you update the order field in your DepartmentPeople when you add/delete items?

Answer (score 14):

See the docs about [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

Answer (score 11):

If you use a explicitly defined `through` model for m2m relationship you can add your own attribute `order-id`. Then You can extend ManyToManyField to populate order-id per your logic on create/update and a model m2m manager that will sort the results when you fetch them by the order-id attribute.

Comment: do you have an exemple or a link?

Answer (score 6):

On Django 2.0, the [accepted answer of Francis Yaconiello](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605077/4081404) works well with the exception of a warning caused by the max_length argument for the `order` field of class `DepartmentPeople`.

Django ignores max_length for integer fields, and will warn you in Django 1.8+.

I would add a unique_together entry in the Meta subclass

```
class Meta:
    #...
    unique_together = ['person', 'department', 'order']
```

to prevent data entry errors.

Comment: thanks for this. my answer is from way back around Django 1.4 or 1.6 so its going to require some porting to work with current versions.

Answer (score 1):

I use that plugin: https://github.com/jazzband/django-sortedm2m
This works just fine
I had some troubles with migrations because i hadn't read usage of the plugin, pay attention on it

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: if you just have a few items in the ManyToManyField, and you prefer not to introduce too much complexity, you could opt to add a `priority` to the `ManyToManyField` and define `ordering` in Meta:

```
class Article(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=16383)

class ArticleContainer(models.Model):
   contents = models.ManyToManyField(Article, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['priority', 'name']
```

A `PositiveSmallIntegerField` ranges from 0 to 32767. The closer to zero, the higher the field will appear.