# Python-Django How to assign an object list to M2M?

Tags: python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates

I have a list like:

```
ol = [<object1>, <object3>, <object2>, <object5>]
```

I want to assign it to a form field which is M2M,
I want to assign it in the same order as given in list,
but M2M has its own ordering scenario, kindly help me out!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not getting you wrong, what you want to do is maintain the order of your ManyToMany Field which would in turn render your form(containing m2m fields) in orderly fashion.

Django doesn't allow this directly. For this you will have to define a [THROUGH Table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

You may consult the above link for the whole and exact method of defining a through model from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

You may find this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602217/define-an-order-for-manytomanyfield-with-django) useful.