# Ordered ManyToMany relation in Django with custom Field

Tags: django, many-to-many

In Django, I would like to have an ordered many-to-many-relation. Assume I have, say, the models `OrderedList` and `Item`, and I want to be able to insert `Item()s` into an `OrderedList()` at a specific index, I want to be able to retrieve the `Item()s` of an `OrderedList()` in their order and also to change the order of `Item()s` on an `OrderedList`

I already found [Define an order for ManyToManyField with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602217/define-an-order-for-manytomanyfield-with-django) and https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-sortedm2m

Both the github repo and the accepted answer in the SO question are working with the same architecture: They create an additional integer field, say `order_index`, on the junction ("Through") table which represents the position of the `Item()` on the `OrderedList()`.

Honestly, I do not like that too much. If I see this correctly, having the order stored on the junction table can create inefficiency when I want to reorder `Item()s`: Imagine, I want to change the position of an `Item()` on an `OrderedList()` which has `n` `Item()s`. This means O(`n`) database updates to reorganize the order indices.

I would like to avoid this. I think of an architecture where I have an ordinary many-to-many-relation and one additional column on the `OrderedList` table which holds a `list` of Item ids, say `items_order`. In this architecture, I need one database update and one list operation on `items_order` - which should be way faster, I guess.

I believe the best way for this is to create a custom model Field. The docs state how to create a custom model Field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/) and I can create my `items_order` field like this. But I did not find how to make a custom Field which, besides creating the `order_list`, also creates the junction table and takes care of updating the `items_order` whenever a new related `Item()` is added or removed from the relation. I think, I should subclass the ManyToMany Field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#ManyToManyField). But I don't know how to do this, so could you give me some guidance here?

Comment: Well a problem is that first of all, many databases have *no* array column, and even if they have one, frequently you can not easily make queries on it (at least not JOIN on these elements, or check if the elements satisfy the foreign key constraint, etc.). Unfortunately an "array-like" object, is not really a good fit in relational databases I think. An alternative might be to make the index a decimal, and thus use `1.5` to insert something between the second and third element.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I also thought of making the index decimal. But this can lead to problems later. Imagine I have the Items (with their index positions) (A,1), (B, 1.5), (C,2), (D,3) and I want to move D to the second position. How would I know, that I have to set its index to 1.25 now? It's a mess. I also know that there is no native array implementation, but I thought a custom Field is a good workaround on this. I think never need to JOIN on the index field, since I still have the relations stored in the junction table.

Comment: well PostgreSQL has for example a "*native*" array implementation, but the problem is that the inefficiency will not be solved, since then you load the array atomically, and store it atomically as well. But you thus have to store a "new array", which takes *O(n)* as well (well the size of the array, and its serialization is *O(n)*). Furthermore I don't know if one can add constraints on the *elements* of the array (well foreign key constraints could be useful here). But I agree that determining the index might be hard, and will probably require two (sub)queries.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In my scenario we are talking about storing an array of length n into one database row instead of n database updates of different rows - mine should be much faster, shouldn't it?