# Editing dynamic choice fields in Django

Tags: django, django-fsm

I have a standard Django blog with a `Post` model, only on the model I have added a `ManyToManyField` for `approvers`, the idea being that the backend passes the post to 2 or more approvers to confirm the content before it is published.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField(Approvers)
```

I will probably learn towards something like `django-fsm` to create a finite state machine for the `Post` model to govern whether it is draft/in approval/published, but I would like to be able to change the `approvers` field so that the number and order of approvers (users) can be changed dynamically by the user.

What is the best way to do this? I thought I could try and change the `approvers` field to a `JSONField` so that users can add / delete / change the order of approvers and then handle the interpretation in the frontend and write some function to interface with `django-fsm`, but this feels like it conflates things too much. Am I missing a simpler route?

Comment: I would rather suggest you to go with a 'Model Manager' to handle things like draft mode/publish mode. I'm still not sure about what you're trying to achieve with the proposed 'approval' design. Finite state machine is definitely an overkill here.

Comment: @Ronnie, Thanks. If there are 3 approvers there are 5 states (draft, approval 1, 2, 3, published). This means a model manager handles 5^5 states which is spaghetti code. Isn't this the purpose of FSM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make another model to do so like

```
class PostApprover(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='approvers')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Approver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To access order in which post(let say with id 5) is approved (descending).you can do like

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=5)
post.approvers.order_by('-created_at')
```

you can change the value of created_at to change the order.
Or you can also make an integer field that determines your order

Comment: Thanks, what if there's more than one post with different approvers and different orders? Isn't a key:value pair better?

Comment: I didn't get you.Can you explain little more?

Comment: Say I have a post with 3 approvers. What if I want to change the order the approvals are applied in?

Comment: see thats why I have mentioned in my last line . that either you can change the value of created_at or you can make an integer field say 'order' in PostApprover model that will set order for each post and approver an order . and you can see the ordered resul by post.approvers.order_by('-order')

Comment: Ok, why would you not do this via a `ManyToMany` `through` field? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602217/define-an-order-for-manytomanyfield-with-django

Comment: Since you have got a basic idea you can try them now.There are only slight modification in using through