# How can I add a field to a many-to-many relationship in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

This is a question about how to add a field to a many-to-many relationship in Django.

I have a model LandingPage and a model Product. (Code below). In my project, LandingPages can have many Products listed on them and those same Products can appear on multiple different LandingPages.

Product is connected to LandingPage via a ManyToManyField.

### My Goal:

I am trying to figure out how to add a field so that I can set the order (1 through 10) for Products on their associated LandingPages. Reminder, Product instances can appear on multiple LandingPages, so each instance will need to have a different order attribute.

Ideally, I'd like to expose this functionality via the built-in Django admin. Right now it shows the relationships table, but not the order field as it does not yet exist. (Screenshots/mockups below).

### My Code:

#### models.py

```
class LandingPage(models.Model):
    """Stores a single LandingPage and metadata.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="The name is only used internally. It is not visible to the public.")
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False, max_length=150, null=False, verbose_name="Slug", help_text="This is not editable.")
    # Additional fields that I do not believe are relevant

class Product(models.Model):
    """Stores a single Product and metadata.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Used internally. Not visible to the public.")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Product is Live on Landing Pages", help_text="Determines whether the product should be visible on the assocaited landing page or not.")
    landing_page = models.ManyToManyField(
        LandingPage,
        verbose_name="Landing Page",
        help_text="The landing page or pages that this product is assocaited with.",
    )
    # Additional fields that I do not believe are relevant
```

#### admin.py

```
# Inline configuration used by  LandingPageAdmin
class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    """Creates Inline table format for displaying Product data."""
    model = Product.landing_page.through
    extra = 0

class LandingPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Specifies LandingPage data in Admin."""
    readonly_fields=('slug',)
    inlines = [ProductInline]
    save_as = True

# Inline configuration used by Product Admin
class LandingPageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    """Creates Inline table format for displaying LandingPage data."""
    model = LandingPage.product_set.through
    extra = 0

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Specifies Product data in Admin."""
    inlines = [LandingPageInline]
    save_as = True
```

### Mockups (for clarity):

#### Current State

[image: current state]

#### Desired State

[image: desired state]

(I added the desired functionality in **red** for clarity. The order integers should be **editable** so that the order can be re-arranged.)

### My Question

How can I accomplish this goal of adding an editable *order* field to this pre-existing relationship?

Should I manually add an *order* field to the product-landingpage join table that was automatically created by Django? If I do that, is there a way to have the Django admin show that added field?

Or should I go about it a totally different way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this.

The solution is create an intermediary model and connect it using "*through*". Example below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Official docs are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Others in my situation may find it useful to read this question/answer as it does a good job of explaining various solutions: [Define an order for ManyToManyField with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602217/define-an-order-for-manytomanyfield-with-django)